# Yosemite - SQLite3 gem installation error - C extensions not supported

Tags: ruby, sqlite, osx-yosemite

I want to use SQLite3 in a jruby project.

```
gem install SQLite3
```

command fails with

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sqlite3:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/h1k3n/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.0.0.0/bin/jruby -r ./siteconf20150809-4559-7o84f5.rb extconf.rb
NotImplementedError: C extensions are not supported
    <top> at /Users/h1k3n/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/mkmf.rb:1
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:940
   (root) at /Users/h1k3n/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.0.0.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:1
    <top> at extconf.rb:3

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/h1k3n/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/h1k3n/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.0.0.0/extensions/universal-java-1.8/2.2.0/sqlite3-1.3.10/gem_make.out
```

gcc version

```
which gcc => /usr/bin/gcc
```

trying to install SQLite3

```
brew instal SQLite3 => Warning: sqlite-3.8.11 already installed
```

SQLite3 version installed

```
which SQLite3 => ~/Android/sdk/platform-tools/sqlite3
```

i thinks this is the culprit.  It probably points to the Android version of SQLite3 instead of a system one and that's why it fails to build the native extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using [JRuby](http://jruby.org), not the standard Ruby implementation, [Ruby MRI](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/).

The [SQLite3 gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/sqlite3/versions/1.3.10) relies on Ruby C extensions, but unlike the standard implementation, [JRuby does not support Ruby C extensions](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/C-Extension-Alternatives):

> JRuby versions prior to 1.6 did not support Ruby C extensions, and even in 1.6 the support is still "in development" and considered experimental. As of 1.7, it has been disabled and will likely [be removed](https://twitter.com/headius/statuses/281091403919003649).

The article above lists recommendations to alternative gems, including for SQLite3.

Comment: Some times google fails us unfortunately... I guess the tag was wrong (Ruby) as this seems to be a JRuby thing, but it did not occur to me that that was the point in this case. ty.
I will try the alternative later when i have time and if it is the case i will accept your answer.